# Request Sync giving a 404 error

Tags: actions-on-google

I have followed this tutorial step by step

https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs

but when I add a lamp or something it gives me this error:

POST REQUEST_SYNC https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:requestSync?key=AIzaSyAB1Nxi3kLQzA5VDr0MgXJ32GDWJ4TA710

POST payload: {"method":"POST","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"},"body":"{\"agentUserId\":\"1234\"}"}

POST /smart-home-api/reset-devices 200 59.124 ms - 2

request-sync response 404 Not Found

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you linked your Google account to the sample already using the Home Control setting in the Google Assistant on your phone?

Comment: When I try to link it, I press the link button but nothing happens.  I put a GSI Client ID in Quick Account Linking ( I used an OAuth client id (web application type) but I still couldn't link it).

Comment: Are you selecting `Authorization code` in the Actions console as the Grant type?

Comment: Yes, I did everything as the readme

Comment: Where are you doing Quick Account Linking? That shouldn't be checked in the AoG console. You only need the API key which you appear to have added.

Request Sync will work after you do the account linking.

Comment: I checked the quick account linking just to see if it worked. It didn't. If I don't check it, it doesn't work either.

Comment: So what happens when you try to link your Smart Home Cloud account in the Google Assistant Home Control settings?

Comment: That was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Followed this
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow

try creating a credential
Create a OAuth 2.0 (webapplication option) client IDs under console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Plugged in the client id which looks like this ............apps.googleusercontent.com under GSI Client ID under console.actions.google.com/project/ ->overview->account linking->configure client->Checked all the check boxes (Not sure if i should) ->GSI Client ID

Comment: Are you getting a 404 or 403?

Try disabling the homegraph api. This should start giving you a 403. Then re-enable it which may give you a 404 or solve the issue.
 Starting yesterday, I happen to get 404s again.
I had to disable n enable homegraph api. And then update the project using gactions update and remove my quick account linking on action console and did a gactions test. Project started working again.

Comment: Unfortuately, I am having 404 error again.
My HomeGraph was disabled for whole day, god knows y i could not enable/get-to/search-for the api to after i disabled it this morning.
I tried account linking and every other thing. It is getting frustrated

Comment: I have disabled and enabled the homegraph api, updated with gactions and did a gaction test and still the 404 error. When I disable the api it gives me a 403, but when I enabled it, 404 again.

It seems like that they are updating the homegraph api so it came offline. Its online now but it is not working for me.

Comment: We are now on the same boat.

Comment: Solved, my problem was that I was't linking my app to google assistant in my phone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was:

in the SYNC request, it requires to have an "agentUserId" parameter and it was missing.

> ```
> "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
>   "payload": {
>     "agentUserId": "1836.15267389",
>     "devices": [{
> ```

https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app

Make sure to send the same id when you send REQUEST_SYNC